# Gesture detector throws exception on 3 finger swipe

Tags: flutter

I am using an mi device having a setting of taking a screenshot when you swipe with three fingers.
So ,in my app when I swipe the `Draggable` buttons on my screen with three fingers the mi takes over the gesture and take a screenshot and my app throws exception resulting in the buttons being stuck somewhere in UI.

So any idea on how to handle the exception?

Exception log:

```
D/ViewRootImpl( 8546): cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting
D/ViewRootImpl( 8546): cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting
D/ViewRootImpl( 8546): cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting
E/flutter ( 8546): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 8546): 'package:flutter/src/gestures/converter.dart': Failed assertion: line 250 pos 18: 'state.down': is not true.
E/flutter ( 8546): #0 _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:40:39)
E/flutter ( 8546): #1 _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core/runtime/liberrors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 8546): #2 PointerEventConverter.expand (package:flutter/src/gestures/converter.dart:250:18)
E/flutter ( 8546): #3 _SyncIterator.moveNext (dart:core/runtime/libcore_patch.dart:151:12)
E/flutter ( 8546): #4 ListQueue.addAll (dart:collection/queue.dart:715:25)
E/flutter ( 8546): #5 _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:83:27)
E/flutter ( 8546): #6 _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:168:13)
E/flutter ( 8546): #7 _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:122:5)
D/ViewRootImpl( 8546): cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting
I/chatty ( 8546): uid=10232(org.chimple.jamaica) identical 7 lines
D/ViewRootImpl( 8546): cancle motionEvent because of threeGesture detecting
```

Comment: Are you using the latest Flutter version? Please check also if you can reproduce with `dev` channel.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes ,it is still reproducing. the problem is when mi device OS 3 finger swipe gesture gets called, flutter throws this exception.

Comment: I'd suggest to create a bug report.